# How to calculate weekly and monthly appearances of distinct string values in SQL Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, rolling-computation

I am new to SQL, and I have a dataset with date values and domain column. Domain column only contains values 'personal' and 'business'. What I am trying to accomplish is to calculate weekly and monthly rolling count for each domain type.

What I thought of doing is creating 2 separate columns - is_personal and is_business - with values 1 for rows where domain_type is of appropriate value. For example, if domain_type is 'personal', then there would be value of 1 in is_personal column. Otherwise, 1 would be in the row of is_business. Then, I was going to calculate the rolling sum.

However, I wonder if I can avoid creating additional columns and perform weekly and monthly rolling count straight from the string column in Google Big Query.

What I tried so far is "grouping by" date column using `DATE_TRUNC(CAST(created_at AS date), ISOWEEK)` to 'roll-up' dates by week periods. When I try any rolling functions on the domain_type column, I get many errors. Some are related to trying functions not recognizable by Google Big Query, some related to the fact that I am working with the string column, and so on.

The ultimate goal I am trying to achieve is calculate weekly and monthly rolling count of 'business' and 'personal' domain types. Please let me know if I can provide additional information that will help. Thank you!

Current look of data:

```
       Date          domain_type

     2017-10-02      personal
     2017-10-03      business
     2017-10-04      personal
     2017-10-05      business
     2017-10-06      personal
     2017-10-07      business
     2017-10-08      personal 
     2017-10-09      business
     2017-10-10      personal
     2017-10-11      business
     2017-10-12      personal
     2017-10-13      business
     2017-10-14      personal
     2017-10-15      business
```

Let's say that during the week of 2017-10-02, a total of 10 users signed up with personal email address and a total of 20 signed up with business email address. During the week of 2017-10-09, a total of 25 signed up with personal email and 30 signed up with business email. Hence, for 2 weeks, rolling count for personal domain type is 35, and rolling count for business domain type is 50.

The output I am trying to achieve:

```
Date          domain_type  rolling_count_for_week
2017-10-02    personal           10
2017-10-02    business           20
2017-10-09    personal           35
2017-10-09    business           50
```

Comment: Please don't link to data, especially in xlsx files. Include example data inline in your question, then also include the results you expect for that example. SO includes text formatting to allow that.

Comment: @MatBailie Thank you for the feedback. I just edited my post. This is my first time posting SQL-based question, hope my edits make the question more digestible.

Comment: Your data doesn't have an email so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I removed the email column to keep question as simple as possible. I already used SQL CASE WHEN code to separate email domains into personal and business from original email column.

Comment: @Arsik36 . . . To be clear, your quest says "distinct string values" and your question has no (interesting) string values for "distinctness".  I really am unclear on what you are trying to do.  Are the emails repeated in the table?  Are duplicates removed as some earlier stage?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry for the confusion. By distinct string values, I mean either 'personal' or 'business'. There are many emails in the table, and I separated them by domain names into either 'personal' or 'business'. Now, I am trying to compute rolling count of 'personal' and 'business' as a weekly and monthly rolling count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Date, domain_type, 
  SUM(IF(domain_type = 'personal', personal, business)) AS rolling_count_for_week
FROM (
  SELECT Date, type AS domain_type, 
    SUM(IF(domain_type = 'personal' AND domain_type = type, 1, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY Date) personal, 
    SUM(IF(domain_type = 'business' AND domain_type = type, 1, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY Date) business
  FROM `project.dataset.table`,
  UNNEST(['personal', 'business']) type
)
WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM Date) = 2
GROUP BY Date, domain_type
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row Date            domain_type rolling_count_for_week   
1   2017-10-02  personal    1    
2   2017-10-02  business    0    
3   2017-10-09  personal    4    
4   2017-10-09  business    4
```

> What if, for one particular week, there is no data on dow=2 but there is data for the other days?

Good point, somehow I assumed that at least one entry per day will exist :o)

See version below that does not have this dependency

```
#standardSQL
WITH calendar_type AS (
  SELECT Date, type
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(Date) min_date, MAX(Date) max_date
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) Date,
  UNNEST(['personal', 'business']) type
)
SELECT Date, domain_type, 
  SUM(IF(domain_type = 'personal', personal, business)) AS rolling_count_for_week
FROM (
  SELECT c.Date, type AS domain_type, 
    SUM(IF(domain_type = 'personal' AND domain_type = type, 1, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY c.Date) personal, 
    SUM(IF(domain_type = 'business' AND domain_type = type, 1, 0)) OVER(ORDER BY c.Date) business
  FROM calendar_type c
  LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table` t
  ON c.Date = t.Date AND c.type = t. domain_type 
)
WHERE EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM Date) = 2
GROUP BY Date, domain_type
```

Comment: What if, for one particular week, there is no data on dow=2 but there is data for the other days?

Comment: my answer assumes that you have at least one entry for each day. do you want me to update it to cover this edge case? or you will be able to do this by yourself based on my answer? let me know

Comment: Thank you, Mikhail! I solved my own problem and will try your code to see if it also gets me the desired output! Your code is a little beyond my knowledge, but I will work on it to decode its syntax. Thank you for your input!

Comment: based on your follow up question in comments - i thought you already tried my initial answer. Have you tried updated one? It should give you what you asked ...

Comment: I raised the first point, not the OP, we even have different names ;)

Comment: @MatBailie - ooops. sorry. my bad. meantime, it is interesting that it is you who asked that question, as your solution does seems to address it

Comment: Umm, my solution rounds all dates down to the start of each week, then groups them. If all seven days are missing the week is missing, granted. Your solution would have previously discarded 6 days of data had the important 7th day been missing.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Your answer to this problem I had just also helped me solve another problem I was facing. Thank you so much for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: glad it helped you :o)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the number of distinct values in a week, use aggregation:

```
select date_trunc(date, week) as wk, email_type,
       count(*)  -- or count(distinct email) if they are not already unique
from t
group by wk, email_type
order by 1, 2;
```

I don't see anything "rolling" about what you are trying to do -- unless, perhaps, you want the count for two consecutive weeks.  If that is the case, use window functions:

```
select date_trunc(date, week) as wk, email_type,
       count(*) as this_week,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by email_type order by date_trunc(date, wk) rows between 1 preceding and current row) as 2_week_count
from t
group by wk, email_type
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, Gordon! I solved the problem myself, and will try your piece of code to see if it also yields the desired result. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  weekly AS
(
  SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC(CAST(created_at AS date), ISOWEEK)   AS created_week,
    *
  FROM
    yourData
)
SELECT
  created_week,
  domain_type,
  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY domain_type ORDER BY created_week) AS cumulative_emails
FROM
  weekly
GROUP BY
  created_week,
  domain_type
```

Comment: Thank you, Mat! I solved the problem myself, finally! I will try your code later today or tomorrow to see if it also yields the desired output!